# Python: How to open up a website with words in searchbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

For example, when the user types a movie, python should open up any site( primewire.ag ( a movie site in this example)) and it should redirect to that site but with the movie name already inputted in the search-bar) I can hard code this for many movies, ( for example [this](http://www.primewire.ag/watch-2754999-The-Avengers-online-free), opens up links for the movie Avengers). But i don't want to hard code it because it's based on the user's choice of movie.

I can't do a common url and concatenate the user's input because the url changes cant be hard coded.

So how would i do this with this small code in python?

```
var2=input('enter movie')
var=input(' Press W if you want to watch, Press exit to quit')
if var=='D':
    webbrowser.open('http://www.primewire.ag/ *WHat do i put here!?*)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like primewire.ag's URLs look something like this:
`http://www.primewire.ag/index.php?search_keywords=monty+python`

So your function should keep that in mind:

```
var2=raw_input('enter movie')
var=raw_input(' Press W if you want to watch, Press exit to quit')
if var=='D':
    webbrowser.open('http://www.primewire.ag/index.php?search_keywords=%s' % '+'.join(var2))
```

For more information on constructs like %s, you can refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) .

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. I actually wanted to link it directly to the page with the links, not just the input ( sorry i forgot to include that in Q). As u can see, in ur example for monty python, when you click the movie, the url is http://www.primewire.ag/watch-881-Monty-Python-and-the-Holy-Grail-online-free. That 'watch-881" code is specifically to that movie. That's the issue i'm having. How do i link it so that it redirects them specifically to their input, cuz every url  is different based on their movie choice.Maybe there's some sort of python library or something, not sure! thanks